# How do I download files on a linux terminal without the traditional commands(like wget)?

Tags: bash, download, alpine-linux, file-sharing

My university has a collaboration with a website where they give us questions to solve in the labs. The website has an IDE and a terminal. I checked and it was using Alpine Linux.
I want to download files on the terminal. But, the problem is that it doesn't have the traditional commands like wget, curl, or even git.

I tried downloading them obviously, but it doesn't have sudo too :/

So, my question is - If I had a file on the internet and I want to download it, what should do I do?

[I am attaching a list of all commands that I think are present on the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHx8u.jpg)

Comment: It's got base64 so you can always run `base64 -d > file` and paste the output of `base64 < file` in the terminal emulator to transfer the contents of `file`. bash, if enabled at build time, can establish TCP connections as well via redirection to fake `/dev/tcp/host/port` a la ksh.

Comment: Please [don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/22222). Instead, copy/paste the text into your question and use the [formatting tools](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to format it as code.

Comment: Copy-pasting isn't allowed on that site. So I thought...

Comment: @Stéphane Chazelas Do you have some documentation/book etc. on this topic?

Comment: @AntasSharma, try `info bash redirection`